# How do I determine a visitor's page of entry? OR: How can I show a different header for a different target group?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I feel like this is a rather complex question, but perhaps you guys have really good ideas on how to accomplish the following:

I have made a website that is going to be used by **Target Group A**. They will enter this website through the homepage.

But I also want **Target Group B** to use the same site, just with a different header and a slightly different homepage (one element is left out). These people will enter this website through a different page on the same site.

How can I let my (WordPress) website determine whether a visitor came in through the homepage for **Target Group A** or through the different page for **Target Group B**? Based on the page of entry, I want my site to show the correct header.

If there is a better way to do this, I am open for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You could start a session, and define a variable as soon as they join, if the variable is already set don't do anything.

```
// Start a session.
    session_start()

// Only save the page if the user has not joined before.
if (!isset($_SESSION['has_joined_before'])) {

    // Get the URL
    $first_page = "http://".$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST].$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];
    // Save the first page somewhere.

    // Don't save the first page again.
    $_SESSION['has_joined_before'] = true;
}
```